# What to insert in a text string to make Excel to understand that has to go in the next cell

Tags: excel, text, tabs, paste, csv

the task I need to accomplish is basically to copy in memory (CTRL + C) a text string that can be pasted splitted in multiple Excel cells, automatically, when i press CTRL + V.

Example below:

I have this text:
"Jay Albert Musician 1982 USA ILLINOIS"

I need each word in a single cell when i press CTRL+V without using Excel to make it split.
My question is: What to add in the string to automatically make Excel to understand that it has to split the word when i paste the string?

I tried something like adding "\t" between each word and  "\n" ad the end but its not working.

Someone has any idea?
Thx in advance

Comment: Not sure you can. Why not use text to columns?

Comment: You could write a macro and assign it to Ctrl+V.

Comment: The point is that my customer asked me a button to copy the text displayed in a web app then paste it in Excel. They want to accomplish this just by pasting the copied text, without using anything else

Comment: Just because your customer wants something, doesn't mean they can get it.

Comment: I agree but somehow Excel understands whenever to use another cell by simply pasting text "as is", meaning that, hidden in the string, there are some special chars that make Excel figure out how to format the text. I want to add those chars to my Javascript text

Answer (score 0):

I just did the thing you asked (working with text import while pasting into a cell) and recorded it as a macro, this is what I got:

```
sub Macro1()
      ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False
end sub
```

Assigning this macro to the Ctrl+V shortcut key might solve your issue.

Comment: The point is that my customer asked me a button to copy the text displayed in a web app then paste it in Excel. They want to accomplish this just by pasting the copied text, without using anything else –

Comment: So, your question is not: how to modify Excel behaviour in order to paste my unmodifyable text into different columns, but how to modify your text so that Excel puts it into different columns by default. In that case: I've just made a simple text `A B C` (the delimiter is a tab character), and simply pasting this into Excel causes the text to be splitted over different columns. You mention having tried using `\t`, are you sure that `\t` is correctly understood as a tab character?

Comment: YES @Dominique, that is indeed what I'm trying to do. And yes I've tried \t \n \r nothing seems to work. I have also tried to simply paste a text separated by the hit of the TAB key like you did... not working.